# Generating netCDF file composed of zeros?

Tags: matlab, netcdf

I need to generate an all-zeros file as an input file for an Earth Systems model (DGVM) I'm using. I have a file with the same dimensions as the zero file. I have R and MATLAB and use a Fedora machine.

Comment: matlab has great documentation, have you tried googling?

Comment: If you can do it in Python, it is very easy by using e.g [xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/).

Comment: Also this might be more suitable to another SE cite.

Comment: If you have a file to begin with, you can open it up and set the variables equal to zero.  I suggest NCL, but there are a variety of programs you could use.  In general, it's easier to read/write an ncf file rather than creating one from scratch.

Comment: If you have an example file, just use the NCO tools, which you may well already have installed: e.g., `ncap2 -v -s 'zeros=foo*0.0' input.nc output.nc`.